# How to convert an asciidoc with cyrillic symbols to pdf?

Tags: linux, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I have created an `.adoc` file and want to convert it to PDF.

I am using Linux Debian and GEdit for writing the .adoc. I followed all the steps to install asciidoc-pdf, RVM, etc. from [here](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoctor-pdf/). And it actually works, but for some reason it doesnt want to convert my file.

I downloaded a readme for Asciidoctor PDf converter and tried to convert it to pdf to see if all is working correctly and it converted with no problem.

When I try to convert my file, it only converts the title and that's it. When I try to convert it to HTML, I get a bit more - the line with the name of the author (my name). And I can't understand what's wrong.

I even tried to write the same file from scratch with no result.

Here is a sample of my file:

```
= Как купить билет на сайте РЖД
Маркиев Владимир <grolribasi@gmail.com>
:hide-uri-scheme:
:imagesdir: img
ifdef::env-github[]
:importatnt-caption: :warning:
:source-highlighter: rouge



Инструкция:: Данная инструкция поможет вам приобрести билет най сайте hhtps://rzd.ru

. Наберите в адресной строке браузера rzd.ru, откроется главная страница сайта.
+
--
image::1.png[главная страница]
--
```

After some reading, I found out that this is due to Cyrillic symbols in my document. I found out that now Asciidoc supports Cyrillic symbols in documents, but you need to specify font family as "Noto Serif" in the header:

```
base-font-family: Noto Serif
```

I tried to set the font family, added the line, but it still doesn't want to convert to pdf.

I guess, now the main question is: how to use Cyrillic symbols in asciidoc.

Comment: Did you consider using Markdown, or [LaTeX](https://latex-project.org/) ? And did you check that your file is [UTF-8](https://utf8everywhere.org/) encoded? And what are your [locale(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/locale.7.html). Perhaps https://ru.stackoverflow.com/ is a better place to ask!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch My doc is in UTF-8 and I need to convert it to pdf since I already have it. My system is in Russian. Ok, I will ask on ru.stackoverflow too, but this one has a larger community, so my first thought was to write here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ifdef

```
ifdef::env-github[]
```

is never closed.

Try to close it that way:

```
ifdef::env-github[]
:importatnt-caption: :warning:
:source-highlighter: rouge
endif::env-github[]
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! However, important caption is displayed without the warning triangle icon in the pdf. It just says "IMPORTANT"

Comment: there is a typo in your "importatnt-caption" attribute

Comment: Yes, I have noticed that after I commented on your reply. After the correction, it says ':WARNING:' in pdf file.